# how to check look for blankspace in char array?

Tags: java, string, char

Lets say i have a string like `"hello world!"`.

I convert this string to a char array, and iterate through the array.

How do I specifically check for the white space between the `o` and `w`?

I tried using a if check saying `if (array[i] == ' ')`, its giving me a empty character literal.

Comment: _its giving me a empty character literal_ - if you are getting that as an error message from the compiler, then you are missing space between the two quote marks.

Answer (score 5):

To check whitespace, use `Character.isWhitespace(char)`. Try:

```
if (Character.isWhitespace(array[i])){

}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
char[] chars = "hello world!".toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  if (Character.isWhitespace(chars[i])) {
    System.out.printf("Character #%d is whitespace\n", i);
  } else {
    System.out.printf("Character #%d is %c\n", i, chars[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you

if(chars[i] == ' ')

Comment: not chars[i] == ' ' but chars[i] == '  ' will work.